# gulp-uglify array of files not executed in order

Tags: javascript, arrays, gulp, uglifyjs

I have a gulp task to concatenate and minify my js files (in filesJs array) in a main file assets.min.js, but my files are not concatenated in order of my array ..

The code :

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var gulpConcat = require('gulp-concat');
var gulpPlumber = require('gulp-plumber');
var gulpSourceMaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps');
var gulpUglify = require('gulp-uglify');

var pathSource = 'web/bundles/sf';
var pathSourceJs = pathSource + '/js';

var pathTarget = 'web/bundles/sf/build';
var pathTargetJs = pathTarget + '/js';

var filesJs = [
    pathSourceJs + '/jquery.js',
    pathSourceJs + '/jquery1.7.2.js',
    pathSourceJs + '/jquery.themepunch.plugins.min.js',
    pathSourceJs + '/jquery.themepunch.revolution.min.js',
    pathSourceJs + '/jquery.stellar.js',
    pathSourceJs + '/custom.js',
    pathSourceJs + '/jquery.jcarousel.min.js',
    pathSourceJs + '/waypoints.js',
    pathSourceJs + '/jquery.easypiechart.min.js',
    pathSourceJs + '/nimble.js',
    pathSourceJs + '/scrollspy.js',
    pathSourceJs + '/jquery.fancybox.pack.js',
    pathSourceJs + '/jquery.appear.js',
    pathSourceJs + '/bootstrap.js',
    pathSourceJs + '/counters.js',
    pathSourceJs + '/slider.js',
    pathSourceJs + '/revolution.js',
    pathSourceJs + '/contact.js',
    pathSourceJs + '/html5shiv.js',
    pathSourceJs + '/respond.min.js'
];

gulp.task('minify-javascript', function () {
    return gulp.src(filesJs, {base: pathSource + '/'})
        .pipe(gulpPlumber(function(error) {
            console.log(error.toString());
            this.emit('end');
        }))
        .pipe(gulpSourceMaps.init())
        .pipe(gulpConcat(outputFileNameJs))
        .pipe(gulpUglify())
        .pipe(gulpSourceMaps.write('.'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(pathTargetJs));
});
```

The output file is minified in this order (bad order) instead of the order defined in filesJs array :

```
"sources":
[
    "js/slider.js",
    "js/contact.js",
    "js/bootstrap.js",
    "js/jquery.js",
    "js/jquery1.7.2.js",
    "js/jquery.themepunch.plugins.min.js",
    "js/jquery.themepunch.revolution.min.js",
    "js/jquery.stellar.js",
    "js/custom.js",
    "js/jquery.jcarousel.min.js",
    "js/waypoints.js",
    "js/jquery.easypiechart.min.js",
    "js/nimble.js",
    "js/scrollspy.js",
    "js/jquery.fancybox.pack.js",
    "js/jquery.appear.js",
    "js/counters.js",
    "js/revolution.js",
    "js/html5shiv.js",
    "js/respond.min.js"
]
```

The concat is in order, but not the minification.

I don't understand why ..

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 0):

If your js files have dependency on each other, `gulpUglify` will possibly re-arrange the order.

Please try disabling functions hoisting:

```
.pipe(gulpUglify({
      compress: {hoist_funs: false}
    }))
```